# Says there is no home file(or any other whatsoever). Upon restart won't let me log in, even though guest session works just fine.

Tags: release-freya, greeter

I was working on unetbootin with my usb plugged in and searching for "downloads" file when the app says there is no "downloads" file. Then I went to check for my self and upon clicking on downloads it said that there isn't any downloads file, after that, all other maps started dissapearing(trash was empty). I restarted the computer and went to login, but it wouldn't let me. Tried several times with restarts, although guest session works just fine. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with lightdm config. Start your system. When you stay at login screen, switch to console with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in with your username and password.

Then type:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.back
```

Now type

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Switch to your login screen with Ctrl+Alt+F7 and try log in again.