# SOLVED Elementary Login wont accept user

Tags: system, greeter

Have been using Elementary (latest) for a week and running well. 
Default admin user as me.
After installing some new software, next time I went to start, I get the login screen which does not accept my pwd, but recycles back to login screen.
However, if I go to bash, and sudo my username and password work perfectly.
If I go to recovery mode that has not helped but I dont know how to reset the Xorg file as trying X -config does not work.

To summarise, there is a login screen whereas before I was logged in automatically, and the login screen will not accept me, but accepts guest login only.

Comment: Note I tried the screen login keyboard to no avail; thats not the issue.

Comment: Try this solution:
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/says-there-is-no-home-fileor-any-other-whatsoever-upon-restart-wont-let-me-l/1451#1451